# Inherited web server runs internal web console program but is not using IIS...need help reverse engineering

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, hosting

An internal (not available outside domain) .Net Core 3.1 console program was placed on a Windows standard server 2016 a few years ago by a previous programmer. I have been asked to create a similar program. So as a reference, I looked at the current program source code using VS 2019.  I thought the current program was hosted by IIS.  But after looking at the server hosting the program, IIS has no sites, or applications set up in the GUI...just 'Start Page'. Is this a case of self hosting? To run the program from my local PC browser, I just type in SERVERNAME:33  (I am guessing the 33 is the port number).  My new program needs to be set up the same way as the current program.  But I don't know where to find the '33' to change it to a different number to avoid a conflict.

NOTE:  When I right click on the current project in VS and choose properties and DEBUG, the port being used shows 5000.  I've also checked 'LaunchSettings.JSON' which also shows 5000.  Is there a HOST file somewhere that would redirect the program to port 33?  Thanks.

Comment: Running `netstat -aon` at command prompt should tell you which process ID monitors port 33 on that server. And then use Windows Task Manager to find the actual executable. From its folder and contents you should learn more about how it was deployed last time. Learn Kestrel settings, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#url-prefixes, as the actual URL/binding can be neither in the project settings nor `launchSettings.json`.

Comment: Thank you.  This pointed me in the right direction.  I think the previous programmer used something called 'Waitress' for Windows to server up the self hosting programs.  I will just need to learn more about the 'Waitress' program and how it works with the port bindings.

Comment: Just another comment that may help others in the future... it turns out the web program WAS using IIS after all.  The reason I didn't see them when looking at the IIS GUI is because I was remoting in with less than ADMINISTRATOR rights.  Once I was given administrator rights, the websites and app pools showed up in the IIS GUI.  Frustrating......

Comment: Even if the web app was hosted on IIS, `netstat -aon` should easily point you to PID 4. The more you know of Windows/IIS, the more commands/tools you can utilize to locate the useful hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Lex li said you could use the command to get the details which application is running on port 33:

1)Open the command prompt as administrator.

2)Type netstat -ano -p tcp |find "33".

3)If the port is being used by any application, then that application's detail will be shown. The number, which is shown at the last column of the list, is the PID  (process ID) of that application. Make note of this.

4)Type tasklist |find "1400". Replace the number with your process id which you get from the above command

you will get the details about which application is running on port 33.